# Can the culture/recreation and the life/arts categories be renamed?

Tags: feature-request, footer

The Stack Exchange categories have bugged me for a long time. Apparently, these categories originate from Area51, which has the following categories

> - **Arts**
>     <sup>*proposals in subjects like art, humanities, media, literature, and music*</sup>
> - **Business**
>     <sup>*proposals in subjects like management, economics, and markets*</sup>
> - **Culture**
>     <sup>*proposals in subjects like language, religion, society, groups, and politics*</sup>
> - **Life**
>     <sup>*proposals in subjects like home, family, education, careers, and self-improvement*</sup>
> - **Professional**
>     <sup>*proposals in subjects like organizations, occupations, and vocations*</sup>
> - **Recreation**
>     <sup>*proposals in subjects like sports, games, and hobbies*</sup>
> - **Science**
>     <sup>*proposals in subjects like the applied, natural, cognitive, formal, and social sciences*</sup>
> - **Technology**
>     <sup>*proposals in subjects like computing, technology, gadgets, and electronics*</sup>

Some of these categories were combined in the Stack Exchange footer. Arts was combined with Recreation, and Life was combined with Culture.

But combining the categories doesn't make sense. If you look at the types of answers Arts sites get, you'll see that they have more in common with culture sites than with recreation sites. Arts questions/answers tend to be more "academic", while recreation answers tend to be more practical.

Could we use the categories Arts/Culture and Life/Recreation instead?

Comment: This would make more sense on its face.